# Laptop speaker cord broken, how bad is it?

Tags: laptop, audio, speakers

About a week ago, I was changing the thermal compound from my laptop's (ASUS N56VZ) CPU and GPU, and while disassembling the case I broke a small cord that goes from the speakers to the motherboard. Here some pictures:

[image]

[image]

I could send the laptop to technical support, but I live in Venezuela, and we have no support here. I was wondering, is this issue easy to fix? If so, could I take the speakers somewhere in my city and get the cord repaired.

Also, what kind of connector is the one in the pictures? I could get one from a store and get it repaired myself.

Comment: The connector itself is very similar to a "audio card to analog CD" type of connector The white end that went into the audio card, not the end that went to the CD.  There was a few situations where both ends were like what your showing there, when it went from a ATIs tv card, to the audio card, and multiend connectors that multiple connectors, it used a connector of that type on both sides.  I measured them at 9mmx4mm. So it is possible to find the connector to apply http://www.ebay.com/itm/Grey-Universal-Audio-Cable-for-most-Sound-Card-to-most-CD-ROM-/150855196089?

Comment: Yeah I'm worried about getting the correct connector, gotta research a little more about the connector you linked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would try and repair it myself... It's not that hard to do, this is how:

1. You need make a note of which wire goes in which hole (I usually label each one with tape).
2. Pull out the other two wires and all four of the tiny metal inserts inside of the white plastic.
3. Trim the wires so that they are the same length.
4. Expose the ends of the wires by cutting JUST the casing off (only about 1/8 of an inch or so).
5. Twist each wire so that it's solid enough to slide back into the tiny metal inserts, and gently pinch the insert with a pair of needle nose pliers (only hard enough to make it stay on the wire, you don't wanna change their shape too much).
6. Slide the insert-capped wires back into their correct holes, and make sure that you position them the right way. They usually have some sort of little tab to keep them in the plastic tip (which you will figure out when you go to pull them out in the first place. I suggest using a large needle or a very thin nail or something to help with getting them out). Once all four wires are clicked back into place, you should be good to plug it back into your computer and turn it on... If you still don't have sound, recheck the inserts.